# Sidebar Toggle button does not show any action

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

The toggle button used in my html code is not working. I tried to design with bootstrap. I'm new to bootstrap. I gave my `index.html` file and `main.js` file. I have no idea where my mistake is. Since I am a beginner, it is very helpful to have your help. Thanks in advance to everyone.

My `index.html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Admin panel</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  

<div class="wrapper">



  <nav id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <img src="default.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      <div class="name" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Name</div>
                    <div class="email">Email</div>
    </div>

    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
      <p>The Providers</p>

      <li>
        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Pending Request</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Policy</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <!-- Page content holder -->
<div class="page-content p-5" id="content">
  <!-- Toggle button -->
  <button id="sidebarCollapse" type="button" class="btn btn-light bg-white rounded-pill shadow-sm px-4 mb-4"><i class="fa fa-bars mr-2"></i><small class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Toggle</small></button>

  <!-- Demo content -->
  <h2 class="display-4 text-black">Bootstrap vertical nav</h2>
  <p class="lead text-black mb-0">Build a fixed sidebar using Bootstrap 4 vertical navigation and media objects.</p> 
  <div class="separator"></div>
  <div class="row text-black">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
<!-- End demo content -->
  
</div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

My `main.js` file:

```
$(function() { 
  $('#sidebarCollapse').on('click', function() {
    $('#sidebar, #content').toggleClass('active');
  });
});
```

My `style.css` file

```
body {
  font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
  background: #fafafa;
}

p {
  font-family: 'poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  color: #999;
}
a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}


/* Side Bar */

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

.page-content {
  width: calc(100% - 17rem);
  margin-left: 0rem;
  transition: all 0.4s;
} 

#sidebar {
  min-width: 250px;
  max-width: 250px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #7386D5;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar .active {
  background-color: #e2694b;
    
}

.components li .active {
  background-color: #261313;
}

#sidebar .sidebar-header {
  padding: 20px;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

#sidebar ul .components {
  padding: 20px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #47748b;
}

#sidebar ul p {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
}

#sidebar ul li a {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  display: block;
}
#sidebar ul li a:hover {
  color: #7385D5;
  background: #fff;
}

#sidebar ul li.active>a,
a[aria-expanded="true"] {
  color: #fff;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

a[data-toggle="collapase"] {
  position: relative;
}

.dropdown-toggle::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 20%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

ul ul a {
  font-size: 0.9em !important;
  padding-left: 30px !important;
  background: #6d7fcc;
}

#content {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  min-height: 100vh;
  transition: all 0.3s;
}

#sidebar img {
  width: 30%;
  

}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  #sidebar {
    margin-left: -250px;
  }
  #sidebar .active {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  #sidebarCollapase span {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    function toggleIcon(e) {
        $(e.target)
            .prev('.panel-heading')
            .find(".more-less")
            .toggleClass('glyphicon-plus glyphicon-minus');
    }
    $('.panel-group').on('hidden.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
    $('.panel-group').on('shown.bs.collapse', toggleIcon);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Admin panel</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  

<div class="wrapper">



  <nav id="sidebar">
    <div class="sidebar-header">
      <img src="default.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
      <div class="name" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Name</div>
                    <div class="email">Email</div>
    </div>

    <ul class="list-unstyled components">
      <p>The Providers</p>

      <li>
        <a href="#">Dashboard</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Pending Request</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#pageSubmenu" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false" class="dropdown-toggle">Pages</a>
        <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="pageSubmenu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#">Page 1</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#">Policy</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Logout</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  
    
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                
            <button data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" class="btn btn-light bg-white rounded-pill shadow-sm px-4 mb-4"><i class="fa fa-bars mr-2"></i><small class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold">Toggle</small></button>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
                <div class="panel-body">
                       <h2 class="display-4 text-black">Bootstrap vertical nav</h2>
  <p class="lead text-black mb-0">Build a fixed sidebar using Bootstrap 4 vertical navigation and media objects.</p> 
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        
    </div>
</div>


  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-w1Q4orYjBQndcko6MimVbzY0tgp4pWB4lZ7lr30WKz0vr/aWKhXdBNmNb5D92v7s" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am new so it is very useful to say where to change?

Comment: you can read more from [here](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-accordion.php) also if my answer helpful can you accept it?

Comment: I gave my whole code to see a little run?